# Images at the same vertical position in multiple columns

Tags: css, block-editor, columns

I have in a page a multiple column layout (in my case 5 columns, but that doesn't really matter). In each column, I have a heading, then an image and then some text, so like so:

`Heading 1     Heading2
Image 1       Image2
Text 1        Text2`

However, the headings are too long to fit on one line, so sometimes they have to be broken into 2 or even 3 lines. Because the headings are different, this in effect causes the images to be at a different vertical position.I would like for all of the images to be at the same vertical position - basically in line accros all the columns.

The only idea on how to do that was to use 2 "Columns" blocks, one for the headings, another for the images and the text. That however doesn't really work on mobile, because there I want it like this:
`Heading 1
Image 1
Text 1
Heading 2
Image 2
Text 2`

and having two separate column layouts would print both headings first, followed by the rest of the content.

I am open to using hand-written CSS or JS, but I don't have a clue how... My theme is GeneratePress if that is of any use.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an html question but, you'd have to write a theme, or at least a child theme.

An absolutely terrible way to do this would be with tables ... but, that'd probably be the easiest way. Something more like this would be sufficient:

```
<div class="row">title 1, title 2</div>
<div class="row">image 1, image 2</div>
```

Comment: I am OK with using a child theme...

Well, the thing you suggest wouldn't work on mobile as well, right? (when the screen is not wide enough so it puts the columns under one another)

Comment: No, no it wouldn't.